# Problems sending data from ClientSide to ServerSide in ASP.NET MVC 5 using Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have a MVC5 Application that works fine using Internet Explorer, but when I try to use Google Chrome, I got an Error, and only says "error".

Here is my javascript code:

```
var priv = 0;
if ($("#EsPrivado").is(":checked")) {
    priv = 1;
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Tickets/Guardar",
    data: "{'RutEmpresa': '" + $("#RutEmpresa").val() + "', " +
               "'CPID': " + $("#CPID").val() + ", " +
               "'ContactoID': " + $("#ContactoID").val() + ", " +
               "'AreaEmpresaID': " + $("#AreaEmpresaID").val() + ", " +
               "'TipoEventoID': " + $("#TipoEventoID").val() + ", " +
               "'FechaInicio': '" + $("#FechaInicio").val() + "', " +
               "'Descripcion': '" + $("#Descripcion").val() + "', " +
               "'EsPrivado': " + priv + ", " +
               "'xLatitud': " + latitud + ", " +
               "'xLongitud': " + longitud + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) { onGuardarOK(msg); },
    error: function (ajaxresult, status) { onError(ajaxresult, status); }
});
```

Also, I have made this in another way, and the problem is the same:

```
var priv = 0;
if ($("#EsPrivado").is(":checked")) {
    priv = 1;
}
var nticket = {
    RutEmpresa: $("#RutEmpresa").val(),
    CPID: $("#CPID").val(),
    ContactoID: $("#ContactoID").val(),
    AreaEmpresaID: $("#AreaEmpresaID").val(),
    TipoEventoID: $("#TipoEventoID").val(),
    FechaInicio: $("#FechaInicio").val(),
    Descripcion: $("#Descripcion").val(),
    EsPrivado: priv,
    xLatitud: latitud,
    xLongitud: longitud
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    url: '/Tickets/Guardar',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ nticket: nticket }),
    traditional: true,
    success: function (msg) { onGuardarOK(msg); },
    error: function (ajaxresult, status) { onError(ajaxresult, status); }
});
```

This is the definition of my Server Method:

```
public ActionResult Guardar(string RutEmpresa, long CPID, long ContactoID, int AreaEmpresaID, 
                                int TipoEventoID, string FechaInicio, string Descripcion, 
                                int EsPrivado, double xLatitud, double xLongitud)
```

And, the other way I define it:

```
public ActionResult Guardar(Models.clsTicket nticket)
```

Can you see wath can cause the error?

Please help me...

Comment: Please provider your controller action as well.

Comment: Have you tried in Firefox and using Firebug to help debug for any possible errors?

Comment: Where does it say "error"? In the JS console? Or in the response body of the AJAX request?

Comment: I add the definition of my ServerSide Method.
I try in Firefox with Firebug, but the response body says "error".
The error ocurs inmediatly, then the Server Side code execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
data: JSON.stringify({ nticket: nticket }),
```

To

```
data: "{'myObject':" + JSON.stringify(nticket ) + "}",
```

Now your controler should expect a object myObject.

```
public ActionResult Guardar(Models.clsTicket myObject)
```

please note, i am using the exact same name "**myObject**".

Comment: I did wath you say, but the error is still the same. The problem is: when I click on Save, the client create the Json data, and the error ocurs when send the info to the Server Side, but once the error message appears, the Server Side code executes and save the data...

Comment: did you try debuging using chrome (key: F12), what is the error message that you see?

Comment: I debug my application using chrome, and the only thing I see is "error"... no error code or something like that...

Comment: Hi all... I still have the same problem... the error says: responseText = "", status = 0, statusText = "error".
Any idea?